# Asynchronous Image Loading Bug

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am hitting a strange bug when it comes to Asynchronous Image Loading, where when I enter a view, the shows up like it is suppose to do, then for some reason the image drops and all I see is the "Loading..." placeholder. I used [this tutorial](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/asynchronous-swiftui-image-loading-from-url-with-combine-and-swift/) when building my loader and the following script is my Article View. I have a Global Functions file, which includes reference to Combine and Foundation for my various functions through out the app. I am just not fully understanding why the image is showing for a brief moment, then calls the placeholder. Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ArticleView: View {
    @Environment(\.imageCache) var cache: ImageCache
    var articleID: Int
    @ObservedObject private var data = Result2()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    init(articleID: Int){
        self.articleID = articleID
        self.data.results.append(Story.init(id: 0, title: "test", image: "", story: "", published: "", author: ""))
        self.loadArticle(CDNLink: "http://\(self.defaults.object(forKey: "domain") as! String)/cdn?funct=fetchArticle&articleID=\(self.articleID)")
    }
    
    var backBtn: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }, label:{
            Image(systemName: "lessthan.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(Color.primaryRed)
                .padding(.top, 6)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
        })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(data.results, id: \.id) { result in
                Group{
                    AsyncImage(
                        url: URL(string: result.image)!,
                        placeholder: Text("Loading..."), configuration: { $0.resizable() })
                        .frame(height: 250)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("\(result.title)")
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(result.author)")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            Text("|")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            Text("\(result.published)")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40, alignment: .leading)
                    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40)
                }
                    Text("\(result.story)")
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: backBtn)
    }

    func loadArticle(CDNLink: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: CDNLink) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            return
        } else {
            do {
                let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response2.self, from: data!)
                print(decodedResponse)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data.results.append(contentsOf: decodedResponse.results)
                    self.data.results.remove(at: 0)
                }
                } catch let err {
                    print("Error parsing: \(err)")

                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct Response2: Codable {
    var results: [Story]
}

struct Story: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var image: String
    var story: String
    var published: String
    var author: String
}

struct ArticleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ArticleView(articleID: 0)
    }
}
```

Edit: I have made the changes suggested and I am still seeing the error, you can see the error live by checking out [this link](https://pasteboard.co/Jtfg4tz.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I created a new solution to patch this issue up and I am very glad that this little work around is working. So, I started looking at what I could do server side to optimize content being pulled into the app. What I did was use PHP to encode the image with base64, then the app pulls it in and decodes the base64 data and the image populates with lightning speed!

Server Side code:

```
$article['image'] = base64_encode(file_get_contents(PATH . "/cache/content/topstory/" . $row['app_article']));
```

Client Side code:

```
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: result.image, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded as Data)!
Image(uiImage: decodedimage)
   .frame(height: 250)
   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi most likely it is due to the fact that you are using `@ObservedObject`. This object is discarded and initialized every time your view state changes and is triggering a view re-render. Try using `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`. The `@StateObject` will be initialized only once in the view.

A `@StateObject` can be also used with an `ObservedObject` model. It is kind of a combination of `@ObservedObject` and `@State`.

Comment: Sweet, I will give that a shot, is data appended into my result the same exact way?

Comment: If your result is a property of the StateObject then it will be appended and only instantiated once.

Comment: Yes, but I will need to switch from using Init to .onAppear{} correct? That way when the view loads it will load the data and append the StateObject. Edit: Within doing that, I am still seeing the same error where the Image flashes in then defaults back to "Loading..."